# Can I get a Google Form json response object without having to set up OAuth?

Tags: google-forms, google-forms-api

I am working on a project to take a Google Form and transpile it into Lua for usage within Roblox experiences.

Take this form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeKIzg67ZWJAr9VXfgODj0xFE73yA40lidbMcEAytP5EhwfZA/viewform

[Form with a simple title and radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBeRZ.png)

Looking at the example response objects from the onboarding guides
https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides
I can infer that the response would look *something* like this

```json
{
  "formId": "FORM_ID",
  "info": {
    "title": "Example Form",
    "description": "Example Form Description",
    "documentTitle": "Example Form"
  },
  "settings": {
    "quizSettings": {
      "isQuiz": false
    }
  },
  "revisionId": "00000021",
  "responderUri": "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeKIzg67ZWJAr9VXfgODj0xFE73yA40lidbMcEAytP5EhwfZA/viewform",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "5d9f9786",
      "imageItem": {
        "image": {
          "contentUri": "DIRECT_URL",
          "properties": {
            "alignment": "LEFT"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "itemId": "0a4859c8",
      "title": "Question 1",
      "questionItem": {
        "question": {
          "questionId": "37fff47a",
          "choiceQuestion": {
            "type": "RADIO",
            "options": [
              {
                "value": "Radio Button Label 1"
              },
              {
                "value": "Radio Button Label 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Ideally I would like to be able to fetch form responses with API keys only, but it doesn't seem like thats allowed with the new Forms api. In that case - automatic fetching of the form information is out of the question (OAuth is far too much overhead / impractical to set up), so what I would like is the **ability to easily fetch the json object for a form i'm the owner of**.

I checked the network traffic for the forms page and it just returns all the HTML required to display, nothing like a the nice Form object you would get from the developer APIs. The "Try it out" feature in the API documentation still requires OAuth.

Comment: In order to use Google Forms API, it is required to use the Form ID of the Google Form. It's `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/{FORM_ID}/edit`. In the case of your URL of `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeKIzg67ZWJAr9VXfgODj0xFE73yA40lidbMcEAytP5EhwfZA/viewform`, `1FAIpQLSeKIzg67ZWJAr9VXfgODj0xFE73yA40lidbMcEAytP5EhwfZA` is not the Form ID. In this case, how do you want to do?

Comment: I'm aware of that, i have the correct ID. Thats not the problem - the problem is authentication.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I'm aware of that, i have the correct ID. `,  I couldn't notice this from your question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.